# How twitter shows tweets from the people we follow

Tags: mysql, node.js, facebook, twitter

I'm writing an api in nodejs and I'm trying to figure out how twitter and facebook shows posts from only the people that we follow.. My initial thought was loop through the posts and filter them according to followers ID, but that consumes a lot of CPU because we've to the loop through all the posts in the MySQL DB. What is the correct logic to show only the tweets/posts from the subscribed people/friends

I would be grateful if someone could through some light.

Comment: At Twitter's scale, this gets highly complex. Take a look at an example of the challenges they were working with way back in 2013: http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/7/8/the-architecture-twitter-uses-to-deal-with-150m-active-users.html

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for the URL

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this what you want?

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-home_timeline.html

Just remove your posts from the result set.